# Create Postgresql table from csv file using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

Hi I looking for solutions that let me create table from csv files. I find solution on another forum. This code looks like this:

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import os
import glob


conn = psycopg2.connect("host= localhost port=5433  dbname=testDB user= postgres password= ************")
print("Connecting to Database")

cur = conn.cursor()
csvPath = "W:\Maciej.Olech\structure_files"

# Loop through each CSV
for filename in glob.glob(csvPath+"*.csv"):
# Create a table name
    tablename = filename.replace("W:\Maciej.Olech\structure_files", "").replace(".csv", "")
    print(tablename)

    # Open file
    fileInput = open(filename, "r")

    # Extract first line of file
    firstLine = fileInput.readline().strip()


    # Split columns into an array [...]
    columns = firstLine.split(",")
     

    # Build SQL code to drop table if exists and create table
    sqlQueryCreate = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ tablename + ";\n"
    sqlQueryCreate += 'CREATE TABLE'+ tablename + "("

        #some loop or function according to your requiremennt
        # Define columns for table
    for column in columns:
        sqlQueryCreate += column + " VARCHAR(64),\n"

        sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]
        sqlQueryCreate += ");"

cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

I try to run this code but i get this error:

```
C:\Users\MACIEJ~1.OLE\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5320/1273240169.py in <module>
     40         sqlQueryCreate += ");"
     41 
---> 42 cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
     43 conn.commit()
     44 cur.close()

NameError: name 'sqlQueryCreate' is not defined
```

I don't understand why i have this error becouse sqlQueryCreate is defined.
Any one have idea what is wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Also, in Windows,  you need to use ```\\``` as a path separator.  i.e. ```"W:\\Jan.Bree\\structure_files"```  Also, if there are no csv files, you will get that error as ```sqlQueryCreate``` is defined inside the for loop.  If there are more than one file, you're going to process the last file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. In Windows,  paths need to have the `\` escaped.
2. your `cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)` and `conn.commit()` are indented wrong.  ditto with `sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]`
   and `sqlQueryCreate += ");"`
3. Edit: Realized that your glob.glob() parameter isn't correct. What you intend: `W:\\Jan.Bree\\structure_files\\*.csv`,  what you actually had `W:\\Jan.Bree\\structure_files*.csv`

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import os
import glob


conn = psycopg2.connect("host= localhost port=5433  dbname=testDB user= postgres password= ************")
print("Connecting to Database")

cur = conn.cursor()
csvPath = "W:\\Jan.Bree\\structure_files"

# Loop through each CSV
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(csvPath,"*.csv")):
# Create a table name
    tablename = filename.replace("W:\\Jan.Bree\\structure_files", "").replace(".csv", "")
    print(tablename)

    # Open file
    fileInput = open(filename, "r")

    # Extract first line of file
    firstLine = fileInput.readline().strip()

    # Split columns into an array [...]
    columns = firstLine.split(",")

    # Build SQL code to drop table if exists and create table
    sqlQueryCreate = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ tablename + ";\n"
    sqlQueryCreate += 'CREATE TABLE'+ tablename + "("

    #some loop or function according to your requiremennt
    # Define columns for table
    for column in columns:
        sqlQueryCreate += column + " VARCHAR(64),\n"

    sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]
    sqlQueryCreate += ");"

    cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
    conn.commit()

cur.close()
```

This should cover the issues; but I have no way of testing the code as
I don't use psycopg2.  I'm assuming that the connect() works.

Comment: I dont get the error no more but code dont make any table. It dont print any tablename.

Comment: Then make sure there are files in your path.

Comment: I checked everything ten times, path is correct and files are in path. I also copy file to another path but still nothing hapend.

Comment: My bad for not being careful.  Your glob.glob path wasn't right.

Answer (score 1):

You do too much work, there is the Alchemy library and things are done quickly and painlessly.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

df = pd.read_csv('W:\Maciej.Olech\structure_files.csv', sep=',')



##> {dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}
# database = bazakot22
# user = foka2
# password = #gg3Ewampkl
# host = 127.0.0.1
# port= 5432


engine = create_engine('postgresql://foka2:#gg3Ewampkl@127.0.0.1:5432/bazakot22')

df.to_sql("table_name4", engine)
```